# Unfortunately Android app has stopped working in xamarin.forms while capturin fingerprint

Tags: xamarin.forms

While I am capturing the fingerprint, my application is crashing.

This is the output while it happens

```
stack corruption detected
12-29 09:24:51.979 F/libc    ( 9373): stack corruption detected
12-29 09:24:52.195 W/google-breakpad( 9373): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
12-29 09:24:52.195 W/google-breakpad( 9373): Chrome build fingerprint:
12-29 09:24:52.195 W/google-breakpad( 9373): 2.2.0
12-29 09:24:52.195 W/google-breakpad( 9373): 25
12-29 09:24:52.195 W/google-breakpad( 9373): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
12-29 09:24:52.195 E/chromium( 9373): ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.119 (alps-mp-m0.mp1-5-arm64) (code 246011960)
12-29 09:24:52.196 F/libc    ( 9373): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9482 (Thread-704)
```

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer our appcentre app is not working properly so we used that sdk in our projected which result in crashing 
but after the new version of that sdk we solved the problem